# How do I disable SSLv3 in an OpenSSH SSH server to avoid POODLE?

Tags: ssh, ssl, vulnerability, poodle

In wake of [the newly-discovered POODLE vulnerability](http://www.zdnet.com/google-reveals-major-flaw-in-outdated-but-widely-used-ssl-protocol-7000034677/), I'd like to disable SSLv3 on all of my SSH servers. How do I achieve this with OpenSSH?

Comment: Is not even affected, check CVE­-2014­-3566

Comment: @Braiam, I was prompted to ask this question because the article linked advises users to secure their SSH servers against this vulnerability.

Comment: It was their mistake. Google, [the one that discovered it](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html) didn't said anything about SSH.

Comment: @Braiam, that would explain my difficulty in finding a way to disable it.

Comment: -1 because SSH and SSL/TLS are two completely different protocols. ZDnet is not a reliable technical source.

Comment: @bortzmeyer while technically you are right, the question is actually not that bad. And a lots of people are probably asking the same.

Comment: +1 because "SSH uses SSL under the hood" is a common misconception -- that phrase appears verbatim in [this article](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-ssh-and-ssl/); getting actual facts from the Internet is surprisingly hard.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not an issue for OpenSSH since it doesn't make use of SSL.

*excerpt - [What is the difference between SSL vs SSH? Which is more secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-is-the-difference-between-ssl-vs-ssh-which-is-more-secure)*

> They differ on the things which are around the tunnel. SSL
>   traditionally uses X.509 certificates for announcing server and client
>   public keys; SSH has its own format. Also, SSH comes with a set of
>   protocols for what goes inside the tunnel (multiplexing several
>   transfers, performing password-based authentication within the tunnel,
>   terminal management...) while there is no such thing in SSL, or, more
>   accurately, when such things are used in SSL they are not considered
>   to be part of SSL (for instance, when doing password-based HTTP
>   authentication in a SSL tunnel, we say that it is part of "HTTPS", but
>   it really works in a way similar to what happens with SSH).
>
> Conceptually, you could take SSH and replace the tunnel part with the
>   one from SSL. You could also take HTTPS and replace the SSL thing with
>   SSH-with-data-transport and a hook to extract the server public key
>   from its certificate. There is no scientific impossibility and, if
>   done properly, security would remain the same. However, there is no
>   widespread set of conventions or existing tools for that.

As further evidence I'd direct you to [RFC 4253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt), which discusses the "The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol". This is SSH's own custom transport layer, it does not use the same one that HTTPS/SSL uses.

> This document describes the SSH transport layer protocol, which
>   typically runs on top of TCP/IP.  The protocol can be used as a basis
>   for a number of secure network services.  It provides strong
>   encryption, server authentication, and integrity protection.  It may
>   also provide compression.

Lastly this Q&A from the security SE site titled: [SSL3 “Poodle” Vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/70719/27973) had this to say about the POODLE attack.

*excerpt*

> The Poodle attack works in a chosen-plaintext context, like BEAST and
>   CRIME before it. The attacker is interested in data that gets
>   protected with SSL, and he can:
>
> - inject data of his own before and after the secret value that he wants to 
>     obtain;
> - inspect, intercept and modify the resulting bytes on the wire.
>
> The main and about only plausible scenario where such conditions are
>   met is a Web context: the attacker runs a fake WiFi access point, and
>   injects some Javascript of his own as part of a Web page (HTTP, not
>   HTTPS) that the victim browses. The evil Javascript makes the browser
>   send requests to a HTTPS site (say, a bank Web site) for which the
>   victim's browser has a cookie. The attacker wants that cookie.

So there is no action that needs to be taken for OpenSSH against this particular threat.

#### References

- [How POO­DLE Hap­pened](https://www.dfranke.us/posts/2014-10-14-how-poodle-happened.html)
- [Taxonomy of Ciphers/MACs/Kex available in SSH?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/taxonomy-of-ciphers-macs-kex-available-in-ssh)
- [Secure Configuration of Ciphers/MACs/Kex available in SSH](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/taxonomy-of-ciphers-macs-kex-available-in-ssh)

#### More reading

- [SSL3 “Poodle” Vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/70719/27973)